# how a virtual address is mapped to address on the swap partition in paging operation

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, virtual-memory

I'm wondering if anyone could help me understand how a virtual address is mapped to its address one the backing store, which is used to hold moved-out pages of all user processes.

Is it a static mapping or a hash algorithm? If it's static, where such mapping is kept? It seems it can't be in the TLB or page table since according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table, the PTE will be removed from both TLB and page table when a page is moved out. A description of the algorithm and C structs containing such info will be helpful.

Whether it's static mapping or hash algorithm, how to garrantee no 2 process will map its address to the same location on the swap partition, since the virtual address space of each process is so big (2^64) and the swap space is so small?

So:

during page-in, how the OS know where to find the address (corresponding to the virtual address accessed by the user process) on the swap partition to move in?

when a physical page needs to be paged out, how does the OS know where to put on the swap partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question : It is actually hardware dependent but the generic way is to keep a reference to the swap block containing the swapped out page (Depending on the implementation of the swap subsystem, it could be a pointer or a block number or an offset into a table) in it's corresponding page table entry.

**EDIT:**
The TLB is a fast associative cache that help to do the virtual to physical page mapping very quickly. When a page is swapped out, it's entry in the TLB could be replaced by a newly active Page. But the entry in the page table cannot be replaced because page tables are not associative memory. A page table remains persistent in memory for all the duration of the process and no entry could be removed or replaced (By another virtual page). Entries in page tables could only be mapped or unmapped. When they are unmapped (Because of Swapping or freeing), the content of the entry could either hold a reference to the swap block or just an invalid value.

For the second part of your question : The system kernel maintains a list of free blocks in the swap partition. Whenever it needs to evict a RAM page, it allocates a free block and then the block reference is returned so that it can be inserted in the PTE. When the page comes back to RAM, the disk block is freed so that it could be used by other pages.

Comment: regarding to your answer to my first question, what I learned (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) is that after the page is swapped out the PTE is removed from the page table &TLB. about my second question: since the swap partition is backing store for all user processses, the location on the swap of a RAM page to be moved out ought to be calculated based on virtual address the RAM page is currently mapped to instead of directly mapping a RAM page to a page on the swap. and TLB is the place where the virtual address of a RAM page can be found.

Comment: I have made some changes to my answer. Check it out! @AlexL

Answer (score 0):

> During page-in, how the OS know where to find the page (corresponding to the virtual address accessed by the user process) on the swap device to move in?

That's can actually be a fairly complicated process. The operating system has to maintain a table of where the process's pages are mapped to. This can be complicated because pages can be mapped to multiple devices and even multiple files on the same device. Some systems use the executable file for paging.

> when a physical page needs to be paged out, after the virtual address for a physical page is looked up in TLB, how does the OS know where to put on the swap device?

On a rationally designed operating system, the secondary storage is allocated (or determined) when the virtual page is mapped to the process. That location remains fixed for the duration of the program being run.

Comment: for my first question, I'm looking to see a example of mapping the virtual page to a loction on a swap partition (not files, for simplification). according to your answer to my first question, the location on the swap partion for a vritaul page remains fixed, then my two questions becomes one. the key thing I'd like to learn how the swap page is calculated. a C structure containing such info or a link to a wikipage will be helpful.